# SSRS Data Driven Subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, report, subscription

Currently I'm working in SSRS trying to generate a unique report for multiple people. In my report I have four parameters: startDate, endDate, monthStart (for MTD values), and ID. I also have it set up so that the report dynamically enters the person's name in a textbox when you specify an ID. How would I accomplish going through and creating a unique .pdf (where all columns are the same yet the data is unique for each person) for each person in SSRS with data driven subscriptions? Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I looked at Microsoft's little tutorial but it didn't explain why things had to be how they are.

Thanks!

Edit: Problem is solved. My queries in the dataset and report were problematic as they kept dropping and re-creating the table I was using.